# How to check if element is valid JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Is it possible to check if object is JSX maybe some function that do that. I'm interested in React and Preact.

```
var x = <App/>
var y = <div>xxx</div>
```

I came up with this:

```
function isJSX(x) {
   return typeof x.props === 'object' && x.props !== null && typeof x.type !== 'undefined';
}
```

Is there a better way? I'm not sure about other libraries like HyperApp and Preact. Is this function reliable? The output came from Babel. Is there a spec that show what should be the output of JSX transpiler?

Here is my [testing Pen](https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/jOOmjVG?editors=1011)

Comment: Since you're checking for the existence of `props` maybe `React.isValidElement` can help you.

Comment: @Dupocas it's perfect, you can add this as answer. I think that only React will be enough.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`jsx` is mainly syntactic sugar for `React.createElement`. You can use `isValidElement` a helper provided by React to check if a given `element` is valid.

```
const isValid = React.isValidElement(element)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need [React.isValidElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#isvalidelement).

Some tests from React sources.

For ReactElement: [https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b87aabdfe1b7461e7331abb3601d9e6bb27544bc/packages/react/src/**tests**/ReactElement-test.js#L298-L318](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b87aabdfe1b7461e7331abb3601d9e6bb27544bc/packages/react/src/__tests__/ReactElement-test.js#L298-L318)

For ReactJSXElement: [https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b87aabdfe1b7461e7331abb3601d9e6bb27544bc/packages/react/src/**tests**/ReactJSXElement-test.js#L156-L166](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b87aabdfe1b7461e7331abb3601d9e6bb27544bc/packages/react/src/__tests__/ReactJSXElement-test.js#L156-L166)